# MVC: Why bother "sending" data to the View

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, controller

I'm very new to MVC, and so I've been scouring the net in an attempt to build my own framework to get a real understanding on how the whole concept works.

Anyway, almost all tutorials out there that deal with MVC always seem to assign data that needs to be displayed in the view to an intermediary variable that is THEN used in the view.

My question is, why bother with that extra step?

Most MVC implementations end up including the view WITHIN the controller... so if that's the case, why waste time/memory/cpu cycles to create an intermediary variable/array that is then passed to the View when the View ends up being included with the controller at the end.

Would it not make more sense to simply use the Controller variables directly in the View itself?

Here's a code example to hopefully clarify what I mean:

```
class News_Controller 
{

public function main(array $getVars)
{
    $newsModel = new News_Model;

    //get an article
    $article = $newsModel->get_article($getVars['article']);

    //create a new view and pass it our template name
    $view = new View_Model($this->templateName);

    //assign article data to view
    $view->assign('title' , $article['title']);
    $view->assign('content' , $article['content']);
    $view->render();
}
```

The render function is basically just an include to bring the View into the Controller to be displayed down the chain. If that's what's going on, one could simply use $article directly in the View rather than go through the hassle of assigning variables to the View.

Comment: The method to pass values from the "controller" to the "view" is diverse among the Faux/Web-MVC frameworks. While reusing the local scope would be just as viable, typically an value object or array is created for looks and the assumption that there's a "collecting" process for view variables.

Comment: in the code above, how exactly do you expect the view object to access variables in the controller object if not passed into the view somehow? also, seems as though you could simply pass the whole article into your view instead of each article variable one by one.

Comment: @dqhendricks, the $view->render() method is basically just 'include('view.php')', so the view is included in the controller. Once that happens, the variables in the Controller become like local variables inside the View file. 

From the examples I've seen around the net, the View always gets included into the controller at some point. 

Is there another way of rendering the View without included it into the Controller, which in turn is included in index.php file... ?

Comment: @Chrys G. I think you are confused as to how variable scope works in PHP. Just because the render method is called from within the controller object does not mean it inherits its variable scope. Methods that belong to the view only have access to the view's variable scope. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: also, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: +1, VERY succinct explanation! Thanks again for all your clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your include inherits everthing from the render() method's variable scope, but the render() method does not inherit anything from the controller's variable scope.

```
class foo {

   public function bar() {
      echo $somevar;
   }
}

$somevar = 'test';
$foo = new foo();
$foo->bar();
```

this code will echo nothing and give you a warning that $somevar has not been defined (if your error reporting is set to show warnings). the reason for this is because methods and functions do not inherit the scope of where they were called from.

php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Thanks for your example. I understand what you're saying but I don't know if it actually represents what happens in the example above.

In the example I posted, variables are declared within a function and then, within that SAME function, another php file is included that directly references the variables declared. Once this file is included, it lives within the function and thus all variables declared in the function are within scope (I guess you could even say they are local).

Comment: @Chrys G. trust me, it does. the fact that an include happens within the method does not affect anything having to do with the variable scope. if the `echo $somevar' was contained within a file that got included in the bar() method, it would behave in the exact same way.

Comment: @Chrys G. you are wrong. in your example the variables are declared in a entirely separate method (main) than where the include happens (render).

Comment: @Chrys G. if the include happened within the main() method instead of within the render() method, you would then be correct.

Comment: you ARE CORRECT! Thanks man. 

I finally realized why I was getting tripped up. My constants defined in the index.php file were working in the view file and so I though that the same would be true for the variables declared in the controller. When I tested out that theory again, it did not work. 

For anyone else reading this, the reason why my constants defined in the index.php file work throughout the project is because the autoloader class is called (via a require) in the index.php file -- where all the constants are defined.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that PHP copies on write. So there is no major performance hit to a simple variable assignment.

As already mentioned, scope is a big issue here. The view is a separate entity from the controller and doesn't have access to its data. Of course, you could pass an instance of the controller to the view, but that's creating an unnecessarily too strict of coupling between the two. The view should be able to work independent of the controller.

So by explicitly assigning data to the view you decouple the two. You will tend to write better and cleaner code as a result.

Second, the process of assigning data to a view could do some data sanitizing or other extra work. For instance, in my framework, I consider all data passed to an HTML view as unsafe. When data is passed to the view (unless explicitly marked as safe) it is encoded via `htmlspecialchars`.

Finally, you can always assign objects or arrays to the view:

```
$view->assign('article', $article);
```

If you do this you generally don't need to assign very much stuff. (And if you do, perhaps your page is doing too many different things.)

Comment: I completely understand what you're saying, but given the way php/includes work, once the View is included into the Controller to be displayed, all variables in the Controller become local variables to the View. 

That's what I have a hard time getting over. I guess it only make sense to pass these to a View class that might perform further manipulation to the data... But then that begs the question as to whether that manipulation should really be occurring in a View class.

Comment: @ChrysG., those Controller variables don't become local to the view, unless you embed a literal `include` in the Controller's method. But even if you were doing that, I would still stand by the principle of minimizing the degree of coupling.

Comment: the thing he is not understanding is that functions and methods do not inherit the scope of where they were called from.

Comment: Just so I finally understand this, if you don't use an include at some point, how would one render/show the view then? At some point, the view file would need to be included in some way in the index.php file which is what's always served. 

The only way I can see of not using includes would be to use a redirect, but I've never seen any (web)MVC use a redirect to display content.

Comment: @Chrys G. the view does include the template... the view does not have the controller's variable scope however...

Answer (score 4):

MVC is a very loose categorization. You are describing one way it **could** work. It's also possible that the variables you use in your controller may not be intended to be used as-is within your view. You may have some sort of template processor that takes in data from the controller, alongside a specially marked-up view template, and spits out the result. Or you may be calling functions/methods from within your view that return ready-made markup.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the scope the controllers variables are in. Unless you make everything global (really bad idea) your concept won't work.

Comment: From what I've seen so far, the include brings everything into scope as it's being included within the same function that the variables are declared.

Comment: @Chrys G. yes, include inherits everthing from the render() methods scope, but the render() method does not inherit anything from the controller.

Comment: I think I'm getting to the part that I don't understand. I understand that render() does not inherit anything from the controller as it is a method of another class, and were this Java for example, one would definitely need to pass variables to the View class/viewfile. 

But since include brings all the variables that are declared in the main() method of the Controller into scope, is the question of scope not a moot point?

Comment: @Chrys G. include only has the same scope as where it was called. since it is called within the render method, it shares the same scope as the render method. include is basically the same as copying and pasting the contents of the file into your code where the include statement is. does that make sense?